# Download csv generated when javascript button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, csv, curl

I have searched exhaustively for an answer and I have found nothing. I have a site i'm working on that has a database which needs to be updated daily. The sql database table is updated by downloading a csv file from another website and importing those entries. I have found countless examples on how to write a php script that will download a csv if there is a url to the csv (www.example.com/test.csv) but the csv I need is generated when the user clicks a button "export to csv". I have checked and checked and there is no url or link. It is a javascript button. So my question is, is there a way to simulate that buttons post request and then save the file? If so, how? I have looked at phantom js and that seems maybe in the ball park but I couldn't find any working examples. I am currently trying to use the curl function in php but that would only be useful if I had a url to point to which I don't. The site is .aspx if that is helpful information.

Comment: Open your console and go to the *Network* tab. Click the button. You'll see the URL you need to get that CSV. Then you can follow any of the other resources that tell you how to download a CSV from a URL.

Comment: Looks like you're building a crawler.

Comment: I tried that and all it says is daily.aspx. There is no link to csv but the csv does download. I right clicked and it said copy curl so i'm going to try that command and see what happens but so far no dice.

Comment: I'm building a fake daily fantasy sports website to put into my portfolio. The csv i'm downloading is the players stats from the season (updated daily obviously) and their price on various websites.